# How to create an avatar for Zopim chat?

Tags: javascript, html, chat, livechat

How I can create an avartar for zopim chat like below ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two places where you can use an avatar;
1) Chat window
2) Badge

You are showing the badge there. It can be done with settings in the backend (dashboard) of Zopim, or using this Zopim configurator:
http://modernminds.nl/zopim-configuration-customize-api/